# SharedPreferences deleted for no apparent reason?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using following code:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(GlobalDefines.SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String test = sharedPref.getString(GlobalDefines.GCM_KEY, "");        
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit(); 
editor.clear();
editor.putBoolean(GlobalDefines.USER_IS_LOGGED_IN, false);
editor.remove(GlobalDefines.USER_NAME);
editor.remove(GlobalDefines.USER_PASSWORD);
editor.commit();
test = sharedPref.getString(GlobalDefines.GCM_KEY, "");
```

The string "test" has a value when I get the value from the shared preferences for the first time; when I remove another value from the preferences and want to get the same value (GCM_KEY) again, it is returned empty.

Why is that?

Comment: Where do you actually put your shared preference `GCM_KEY` value?

Comment: You're calling `editor.clear()` - that deletes all values from the `SharedPreferences` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`editor.clear()` tells the editor that you want to remove **ALL** values from your SharedPreferences. Remove this line and you will see the expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!